# Extract first word to first space - POSTGRES

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to extract only the first word to the first space.

I used the following query:

```
select upper(substring(substring(descripcion,28),0,length(substring(descripcion,28))-position(' ' in reverse(substring(descripcion,28)))+1)) from evento where descripcion ~ 'Act. datos:Actualización';
```

But it gives me back everything, not just the first word before the first space.

How can I get the following result

1. John
2. Elena
3. Maria
4. Marcus
5. Mario
6. Ana
7. Pedro

etc.

Answer (score 5):

Use [`split_part`](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-split_part/) with space as delimiter to get the first string, e.g.

```
SELECT split_part('CARMEN SANDIEGO',' ',1);

 split_part 
------------
 CARMEN
```

So in your case it should be something like

```
SELECT 
  upper(
   split_part(
    trim(substring(descripcion,28)),' ',1))
FROM evento
WHERE descripcion ~ 'Act. datos:Actualización';
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=138d982d40d02be675b5bfaa8515a05c)

Answer (score 0):

Use regexp_replace:

```sql
select upper(regexp_replace(
    descripcion,
    '^Act\. datos:Actualización de ([a-z]+).+$', 
    '\1'))
  from evento 
  where descripcion ~ '^Act\. datos:Actualización de ([a-z]+).+$';
```

Pls. note that to make it simpler the regex for filtering and text extraction is the same. I have fixed a bit yours and added a capturing group.